# Returning HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I am using some JavaScript to create new HTML elements and then I return them using the MooTools inject method.

```
 display: function() {
        var threadTitle = new Element('h2',{
            'class': 'postItem',
            'data-id': this.id,
            'text': this.title,
            'href': '#',
            events: {
                click: function(){
                    $('newComment').setStyle('visibility', 'visible');
                    var id = this.get('data-id');
                    $('thread').value = id;
                    callThread(id);
                }
            }
        });

        var deleteT = new Element('a',{
            'class': 'deleteItem',
            'data-id': this.id,
            'text' : 'Delete',
            'href' : '#',

            events: {
                click: function(){
                    var deleteID = this.get('data-id');
                    deleteThread(deleteID)
                }
            }
        });

        var editBtn = new Element('input',{
            'class': 'mt-btn',
            'value': 'Edit',
            'type': 'button',
            'data-id': this.id,
            'text' : 'Edit',
            'href' : '#',
            events: {
                click:  function(){


                }
            }
        });



        deleteT.inject(threadTitle);
        editBtn.inject(threadTitle);
        return threadTitle;
    }
});
```

This obviously returns the new elements inside of the h2 as I inject into it. Is there a way to create each one outside of the H2, so in a sense

```
<h2></h2>
<a></a>
<input></input>
```

I have tried using the MooTools way of using `editBtn.inject(threadTitle, 'after');` but this doesn't seem to work and nothing gets returned. So by question is how do I return the elements on the page one after each other not injected into the h2 element.

Comment: Wait, are you using jQuery?

Comment: The reason I stated this as any question I have posted asking for a MooTools answer I seem to get a jQuery answer. Thanks for this comment though really helpful.

Comment: I'm totally joking. Trust me, I understand completely. If you tag `mootools` and not `jquery`, you shouldn't get a jQuery answer

Comment: Can I put "Use jQuery" as my answer?

Comment: I don't use mootools, but are you looking to return all three references to those elements? Why don't you return an array with the 3 variables inside?

Comment: I am looking to return each HTML element one after each other, I don't know how to return elements with out using the inject method.

Comment: @Ian Yes, you would think would you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430491/ajax-reload-div-after-complete

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, functions cannot return more than one value.

Comment: @joshuahornby10 Exactly, I would **hope**. But I **know** the world isn't perfect and it happens more often than it should

Comment: @ExplosionPills Of course you can...you know how it'll end up :)

Comment: I am creating each element and the only way i can 'return' them on the page is injecting them into the h2 element. I wish to return them so they are not injected into the h2 but returned one after another like the second code block in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried using the MooTools way of using `editBtn.inject(threadTitle, 'after');` but this doesn't seem to work and nothing gets returned.

It think the problem there is that `threadTitle` doesn't, as of when you're doing that, have a parent. If it doesn't have a parent, MooTools will struggle to inject anything "after" it as doing so requires that it inject into the *parent* element.

If you put `threadTitle` into the DOM first, I suspect `editBtn.inject(threadTitle, 'after');` and such will work fine.

Compare this, which doesn't work: [Live Copy](http://jsfiddle.net/p2M3h/1/)

```
var p = new Element('p');
p.set("html", "This is the <code>p</code> element");

var div = new Element('div');
div.set("html", "This is the <code>div</element> inserted <em>after</em> the <code>p</code>");
div.inject(p, 'after');

p.inject(document.body);
```

...with this, which does: [Live Copy](http://jsfiddle.net/p2M3h/)

```
var p = new Element('p');
p.set("html", "This is the <code>p</code> element");
p.inject(document.body);

var div = new Element('div');
div.set("html", "This is the <code>div</element> inserted <em>after</em> the <code>p</code>");
div.inject(p, 'after');
```

...the difference being that the `p` element has been added to the DOM before we try to inject the `div` after it.

Comment: Ah yes I see. Perfect, one question instead of injecting into the document.body can I inject into a div? would this be p.inject($(divName));

Comment: @joshuahornby10: As long as the element has a parent, it shouldn't matter what that parent is. For instance, look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/p2M3h/2/ The parent isn't even in the DOM yet at the point I inject after one of its children. The issue (I think) is that `bar.inject(foo, 'after')` is basically implemented as the raw DOM operation `foo.parentNode.insertBefore(bar, foo)` and so if `foo` has no parent, it can't work.

Comment: Did somebody say MooTools!?