# Auto-refresh DIV after 10 minutes

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would like one DIV on my page to automatically refresh after 10 minutes. I don't want to reload the entire page, just the one part.

This is the PHP that I am using:

```
function fblikes() {
$pageID = $_GET['id'];
$pagename = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $pageID));
echo $pagelikes->likes;
}
```

And this is what I want to be refreshed automatically:

```
<div>
<span><?php fblikes(); ?></span>
</div>
```

Can somebody help me with this please?

Comment: Ooooh, I know this one, the answer is -> `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">`

Comment: @adeneo too bad that doesn't fit the *"one DIV"* part of his question  ;)

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes - and it's a horrible invention that should'nt be used. Updating content every ten minutes is usually bad for user experience, and even news sites that does this is annoying, updating the front page when you're trying to read something.

Comment: Well afaics he's just trying to assure minor client side data (the likes of a specific FB page) is passively kept up to date for when a user keeps a tab open unreasonably long. That is an acceptable use case imho.

Answer (score 3):

[Quoting myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430644/1729885):

> You cannot 'reload a div'. A `div` is just a single element on an
>   entire webpage, and on its own it has no URL it was loaded from, so it
>   cannot be reloaded. You can set/replace the contents of a div with an
>   Ajax call, but that's definitely not 'reloading' - you'd need to
>   explicitly define the URL to load its new content from.

You need to write some Javascript, use `setTimeout` to schedule a function for execution in 10 minutes, and then use an Ajax call to retrieve JSON or HTML data that is then either parsed or placed in the relevant `span` element.

In your very specific situation you can make your own life easier by using the Facebook clientside Javascript API, and just issue a `FB.api(...)` call every 10 minutes since that appears to be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

use JQuery/Ajax for that.

Example:

```
function reloadDiv() {  
  $.ajax({
    url: URL_TO_YOUR_PHP_SCRIPT,
    type: 'get',
    success: function(result) {
       if (result) {
          $('#YOUR_DIV').html('<span>' + result + '</span>');
       }
    } 
  });
}
```

and use setTimeout to reload this div every 10 minutes like:

```
setInterval("reloadDiv()", 600000); // 60 * 1000 * 10
```