# Refresh div without load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with some content, I want the div to auto refresh every x seconds. I don't want to use load because it will call some other page and the div content is not dynamic.

This is what I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshDiv() {
       gg1.refresh(getRandomInt(0, 100));
    }
    $(document).ready(function () { setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000); });
</script>

<div id="first">a</div>
<div id="second">b</div>
<div id="gg1">c</div>
```

Comment: what is the point of reloading if it does not change?  If it does change, how does it change without ajax?

Comment: So if not with ajax, what do you want to refresh it with ?

Comment: Do you just want to change the contents of the div?  If so, just use .val or .html where you have refresh.

Comment: no i dont want to change div content only reload,just like page reload

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16618745/1729885

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-refresh DIV after 10 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618719/auto-refresh-div-after-10-minutes)

Comment: you can take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306105/randomize-numbers-with-jquery

Comment: @Nesmar i dont want to change content of div

Comment: If you do not want to change the content, why should the `div` be refreshed?

Comment: @Martin because if i make any changes in div it will get updated ,without refreshing page

Comment: If you do not want to change the content of the div, then why it will be refresh.. What are you trying to achieved here? You can then use the `.html` or `.text` to change the content of the div.

Comment: Makes no sense? You can't "reload" an element, you can change it's content, but if you don't want to change the content, and don't want to reload the page, just leave it alone?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you only want to update the `div` with a random number all 5 seconds?
Then I think this code from [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyf69/) will help you.

```
function getRandomInt() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
};

function refreshDiv() {
    $('#gg1').html(getRandomInt());
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000);
});
```

Comment: if i dont want random number,i want same content only div refresh

Comment: Then use instead of `$('#gg1').html(getRandomInt());` your content as html: `$('#gg1').html('yourcontentgoeshere');` or for only refresh same content something like: `$('#gg1').html($('#gg1').html());` ;-P

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `refresh` is a valid command (I could be wrong).
I would do something like this:

```
var cDIVCONTENT = "a";
function refreshDiv() {
   gg1.value = cDIVCONTENT;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
   setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000); 
});
```

This will continually set the value of the `gg1` div to be `cDIVCONTENT`
Is this what you want?

Comment: i dont want to change content

Comment: It's just an example. You could set `cDIVCONTENT` to be the original content of the DIV and then you're just resetting the content. So for example, if the user changes it, then it will be reset after each interval

Answer (score 0):

first you create a function for set content

```
function changeDIV()
{
    $('.eg').html('text');
}
```

and call with inteval

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   setInterval(changeDIV,5000); 
});
```